# Flutter: AlertDialog not showing

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-alertdialog

it's my first time working with flutter and I'm currently trying to implement a map with different icons. by clicking on an icon a pop up window should appear. I've watched some youtube videos now and tried to implement an AlertDialog in different ways now but everytime i click on an icon the pop up window won't show up. I'd really appreciate some help, thank you!!
is it possible that the markerlayeris blocking the interaction?

here's my relevant code snippet:

```
return MarkerLayer(
                    markers: pois.map(
                          (poi) =>
                              Marker(
                                width: 30.0,
                                height: 30.0,
                                point: LatLng(poi.latitude, poi.longitude),
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.location_pin,
                                    size: 40.0,
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                  ),
                                  onTap: () {
                                    showDialog(
                                      context: context,
                                      builder: (context) {
                                        return AlertDialog(
                                          title: Text('title'),
                                          content: Text('description'),
                                          actions: [
                                            TextButton(
                                              child: Text('Cancel'),
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        );
                                      },
                                    );
                                    },
                                  ),
                              ),
                    ).toList(),
                  );
```

Comment: Whenever you are using alert dialog box, always pass a "context" of the stateful/stateless widget class. In this code MarkerLayer has a method so pass context in the method only then it will work or read this article
https://researchthinker.com/why-is-my-alertdialog-not-visible-in-my-flutter-app-and-what-could-be-the-reason-behind-it/

Comment: and use `rootNavigator: true`

Comment: @paul i'm sorry to bother u sir but i really suck at coding. what do you mean with passing the context into the markerlayer??? return Markerlayer(context)??

Comment: @7feetal, popup window will be visible if you use context as a parameter, declare method like "showAlertDialog(BuildContext context){return MarkerLayer(context)....} or you can follow above link example showAlertDialog

Comment: thank u @paul i'll give it another try